# How to understand and use asyncio in Python using PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio

I trying to learn how to use the asyncio framework in Python. I have the below code but it is giving the error:

> event loop stopped before the future completed.

Also please update where to capture the outputs of the code.

Code:

```
import asyncio
import aiopg

dsn = 'dbname=dvdrental user=postgres password=password host=127.0.0.1'


async def go():
    pool = await aiopg.create_pool(dsn)
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("Select * from actor")
            ret = []
            async for row in cur:
                ret.append(row)
            assert ret == [(1,)]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(go())
```

Comment: What did you find when you searched for that error?

Answer (score 2):

The pool is not closed before exit from `go()` coroutine and loop stopping.

Use `async with aiopg.create_pool()` instead of `await aiopg.create_pool()` or explicitly call `pool.close()`/`await pool.await_closed()` at the end of coroutine.